# Can't made authenticated requests with Mocha and Supertest

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I'm trying to test an API with Mocha and Supertest without lucky to make it work.
I have the following code:

```
var supertest = require('supertest');  
describe('Routing', function() {
    var url = 'http://example.com';
    var server = supertest.agent(url);

    var credentials = {
        user: 'username',
        pass: 'password'
    };


    describe('Login', function() {

        it('should login ok given valid credentials', function(done) {
            server
                .post('/login.php')
                .send(credentials)
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }                   
                    server.saveCookies(res);
                    done();
                });
        });


        it('should correctly make an authenticated request', function(done){
            server
                .get('/api/me/accounts?_=1449865354112')
                .end(function(err,res) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    res.status.should.be.equal(200);
                    done();
                });
        }); 
    });
});
```

The login request works fine, I get authenticated. The second call throws a 401 status.
I read the documentation but I can't make it work.

What is wrong?
thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I finally get authenticated by sending the params using `.field('user', 'myUsername')` and `.field('pass', 'myPassword')`.

Also I have to persist the cookie between calls:
`cookie = res.headers['set-cookie'];` when I get authenticated, and `.set('cookie', cookie)` in the next requests.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the session (cookie) is not persisted between your two tests.

- First you should do the two calls inside the same test.
- Second i remember that i have used superagent to persist the session between two calls to the same server. But it seems that supertest now expose the agent to persist the session.

  ```
  var supertest = require('supertest');
  var app = express();
  var agent = supertest.agent(app);
  // then you can persist cookie
  agent
    .post('/login.php')
    .auth(credentials)
    ...
  ```

edit : 
here is an example of how i have used superagent for tests :

```
    var request = require('superagent');
    var postData= {
      email: 'john@test.com',
      password: 'test'
    };

    var user1 = request.agent();
      user1.post('http://localhost:3000/user/login')
        .send(postData)
        .end(function (err, res) {
          expect(err).to.not.exist;
          expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
          var result = res.body;
          expect(result.data.message).to.equal('Login successful');

          user1.get('http://localhost:3000/user')
            .end(function (err, res) {
              expect(err).to.not.exist;
              expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
              var result = res.body;
              expect(result.data.email).to.equal('john@test.com');
              done();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, but where do I have to put the Domain in that code? I still can't make it work :(

Comment: I have added an example of how i have used superagent for my unit tests.

Comment: Have you fixed your problem ?

Comment: Hi @Sachacr, I've updated the question with the FIX.

Answer (score 0):

`.send()` is for your data. `.auth()` is for your credentials. Try:

```
it('should login ok given valid credentials', function(done) {
    server
        .post('/login.php')
        .auth(credentials)
        .send({"some": "value"})
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                done(error);
            }                   
            server.saveCookies(res);
            done();
        });
});
```

See http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/docs/test.html for a bit more information on supertest.